# PDE Separation of Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm trying to find a solution to:
$v_t = kv_{x x} , 0 < x < l, 0 < t < ∞$

$v(0, t) = 0$

$v_x(l, t) = 0$

$v(x, 0) = −U$

I have:

$v(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$

$X(x)T'(t) - kT(t)X''(x) = 0$

$\frac{T'(t)}{kT(t)} = \frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} = -\lambda$

$X''(x) = -\lambda X(x)$

$\delta^2 = \lambda$

$X(x) = C\cos(\delta x) + D\sin(\delta x)$

$X'(x) = -C\delta\sin(\delta x) + D\delta\cos(\delta x)$

$X(0) = C+ D = 0 => C=-D$

$X'(l) = -D\delta\sin(\delta l) + D\delta\cos(\delta l) = D\delta[\sin(\delta l)+\cos(\delta l)] = 0$

This is wear I keep getting suck

The correct value of $\delta$ is suppose to be $\frac{n + (1/2)}{l}\pi$ but I don't see how that is possible

Comment: Your error is in $X(0) = C + D$. That's not true. $\sin(0) = 0$ after all so it is actually $X(0) = C$.

Comment: X(0) = C, NOT C+ D.